# Why my apk for my xamarin app does'nt work?

Tags: c#, xamarin, apk

I have an application (Xamarin app) that works in debug and release.

I try on emulator (in visual studio 2017) and on my phone (in debug mode) and no problem.

I do an apk from release, but only the home page works? When i try to go on other page i have an error "the application has stopped" and i don't know why?!

How could I go about this?

-I try to set "None" in options but no difference.
-I have no methode called moveTaskToDisplayIfNeeded.
When the App crash i have this in logkat.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOh2i.jpg

Comment: Open Logkat and find exception.

Comment: OK, monitor is now removed from SDK, see the following article how to view logkat https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=vswin

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Do one thing, while creating APK, have linking set to "None" in options.

rebuild and take new APK and give it a try

Comment: Do you have a method called moveTaskToDisplayIfNeeded() ? If yes then it is throwing the exception

Comment: Did you take the apk from your Debug build or from Release? A Debug apk doesn't contain everything your app needs. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/app-package-size#debug-packages

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem with change option and use SDK assembly only.